# Mark()/Reset BufferedReader in java

Tags: java, reset, bufferedreader

I thoroughly understand how the mechanism mark and reset works:
However I would like to know why the following code taken from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedreader_mark.htm), works even if I replace br.mark(26) with br.mark(0). Since the parameter is the mumber of char to be read ahead of the mark. If I put 0 as argument it should not read anything. instead it works as if I did not change anything. 
Why does it behave in that way?

```
br = new BufferedReader(isr);
     // reads and prints BufferedReader
     System.out.println((char)br.read());
     System.out.println((char)br.read());
     System.out.println((char)br.read());
     // mark invoked at this position
     br.mark(0);


     System.out.println("mark() invoked");
     System.out.println((char)br.read());
     System.out.println((char)br.read());
     System.err.println("The Thing to be said:"+(char)br.read());

     // reset() repositioned the stream to the mark
     br.reset();
     System.out.println("reset() invoked");
     System.out.println((char)br.read());
     System.out.println((char)br.read());
     System.out.println((char)br.read());
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark(int) -> *may* fail. There's no guarantee that it will. While I don't care for Java's "Eh, might do this or that" thing ... it's fairly common.

Comment: @BrianRoach The stream gets reset, it's the amount of characters read after the mark that overcome the limit I set. It should have reset the buffer to when I called mark() and then not returning anything in the next read() call. But it fails.. so it fails also to set the limit of characters ahead? What does it serve then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not a strict limit, it's just advice.  as the javadoc states:

> An attempt to reset the stream after reading characters up to this limit or beyond *may* fail.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: The stream gets reset, it's the amount of characters read after the mark that overcome the limit I set. It should have reset the buffer to when I called mark() and then not returning anything in  the next read() call. But it fails.. so it fails also to set the limit of characters ahead? What does it serve then?

Comment: @Rollerball - yes, i understand how mark/reset work.  as the documentation states, it _may_ fail.  in some situations it will fail, in some it won't.  in the case of BufferedReader, as long as you stay within the current buffer, it won't fail.  it only checks the read-ahead flag when it has to load a new buffer from the underlying stream.  it serves the purpose of advising BufferedReader (or any other Reader) how much "old" data it needs to keep track of.